# Lazy Loading Modules Always Returns App Component

Tags: angular

I'm setting up Lazy Loading modules in my angular app. But lazy loading doesn't return the necessary component for the route.

I have tried the lazy loading method in Official Angular documentation (https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules).

My AppRoutingModule routes

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'admin',
    loadChildren: () => import('./admin/admin.module').then(mod => mod.AdminModule)
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: AppComponent
  },
];
```

My AdminRoutingModule

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: DashboardComponent },
];
```

When visiting the both http://localhost:4200/, http://localhost:4200/admin route it shows app component works. I'm expecting the dashboard component data to be shown in the admin route.

Comment: Did you add the router-outlet element inside your template ?

Comment: I added once in app.component.html. It loaded both Dashboard and App Components. Is it normal behaviour?

Comment: Yes it is the normal behavior, the AppComponent is the default component that Angular create and load into the app root selector inside index.html, you can remove the route that define AppComponent

Comment: Thanks. I thought it loads the AdminModule directly. Thank you for clarifying